# Passing a char** to a function

Tags: c, pointers, char

I will summarize my code because it's quite big. In `main` I have this:

```
int main() {
    char **name_ptr;

    int ret = get_name(name_ptr);
    if(ret == 1)
        printf("main: %s\n", *name_ptr);
}
```

In the function `get_name`, I have this:

```
int get_name(char **name) {
    char buffer[30]; 
    name = malloc(sizeof(char **));
    *name = &buffer[0];
    printf("get_name: %s\n", *name);
    return 1;
}
```

The buffer comes from a tcp connection and its correct, which is a string saying "the_name".

And my output is

```
get_name: the_name
main: ��i�
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The buffer is not allocated using `malloc`, which means it is invalid after the function has returned

Comment: in `get_name`, use `(*name)` in left hand assignment expression, from `main`, call `get_name(&name_ptr);`

Comment: @newguy  The function does not make sense. First of all the array buffer is uninitialized. And secondly the function returns  pointer to a local array that will not alive after exiting the function.

Comment: the buffer receives is assigned over a tcp connction that would be too big to put here. How can i alloc the buffer then?

Comment: and `name = malloc(...);` won't be reflected outside `get_name` so after `get_name(a)` if `a=NULL` before it will still be `NULL` after the call, worse you have introduced a memory leak and calling `free(a)` after calling the function won't free it(I think it will segfault but I'm not sure)

Comment: @newguy Simply `*name = malloc(30)`.

Comment: Put simply, in C, function(thing) cannot ever change thing.  The thing argument is passed by value and so copied into the parameter used inside the function. You can modify the parameter copy, but that does not modify the argument in the caller.   You MUST understand this essential fact.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple people have already pointed to problems in this code. I don't want to repeat them, but I want to present an approach that will help with passing OUT values through pointers.

What you probably want is this:

```
int main() {
    char *name_ptr;

    int ret = get_name(&name_ptr);
    if(ret == 1)
        printf("main: %s\n", name_ptr);
}
```

Notice how `name_ptr` above became a simple `char *` and its address is passed to the func. This doesn't change `get_name's` prototype but makes consuming `name_ptr` easier in the calling func (main).

Now:

```
int get_name(char **name) {
    char buffer[30] = "hello"; // data read fromsocket
    size_t len = 5; // size of data read from socket
    *name = malloc(len+1);
    memcpy(*name, buffer, len);
    *name[len] = 0;
    printf("get_name: %s\n", *name);
    return 1;
}
```

Notice that inside `get_name` I only use `*name`. I never use `**name` or `name`. This approach makes things much simpler in terms of pointer logic.

I've added one extra byte for the terminating null. This is obviously optional, i.e. if data over socket comes null-terminated. Alternatively you can modify `get_name's` prototype to return the len:

```
int get_name(char **name, size_t *name_len) {
    char buffer[30] = "hello"; // data read fromsocket
    size_t len = 5; // size of data read from socket
    *name = malloc(len);
    memcpy(*name, buffer, len);
    *name_len = len;
    printf("get_name: %.*s\n", *name_len, *name);
    return 1;
}
```

Notice again how I use `*name_len` instead of `name_len`.

And now the caller would do:

```
char *name_ptr;
size_t len;

int ret = get_name(&name_ptr, &len);
if(ret == 1)
    printf("main: %.*s\n", len, name_ptr);
```

So the rules that I recommend to follow are:

1. Pass variables by taking their address with `&`
2. Inside the callee, always reference the variables as `*varName`. Never use `varName` directly.

These simple rules should make your life easier.

Hope this helps!